# Error when connecting my PHP app with the Mysql Database via Server (Plesk)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing an application in **PHP** to receive a **Post and Add directly to the database**, but when it comes to testing the connection using the server's IP. it gives the error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'TESTE'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Note: it is not localhost, it is running on the PLESK server.

[Database Image, IP,Table,database name with ilustrative data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5c9U.png)

Connection Code (PHP)

```
const DBCONNECTION = 'mysql';
const DBHOST = '112.115.225.365';
const DBNAME = 'teste_whats';
const DBUSER = 'teste';
const DBPASS = 'teste';

$connPdo = new \PDO(DBCONNECTION.': host='.DBHOST.'; dbname='.DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

When making the standard localhost connection using the local database it opens correctly and inserts correctly but when I change the database on the server it gives the error

Comment: does the user `teste` have access to connect to the database via the sites IP?

Comment: `112.115.225.365` is 100% not the IP of the server.. nor is it a valid IP at all